# How to extend the following Java class in Scala: class A<T extends Comparable<? super T>>

Tags: java, scala

I need to extend a Java class (from a library) of the following type:

```
public class A<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
}
```

I tried to implement the extending Scala class as:

```
class B[T <: Comparable[_ >: T]] extends A[T] {
}
```

Unfortunately, this Scala class does not compile with Scala 2.12.1:

```
Error:(4, 25) illegal cyclic reference involving type T
class B[T <: Comparable[_ >: T]] extends A[T] {
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try defining an alias for this nested type:

```
object B {
  type ComparableBySuper[LUB] = Comparable[_ >: LUB]
}

class B[T <: ComparableBySuper[T]] extends A[T]
```

Comment: That's it!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Never define types using lowercase chars.

Comment: @flavian sure, I just did it for the sake of example

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a great usage of what Scala calls type lambdas, which follows roughly the same approach as the accepted answer but sidesteps the requirement of having to nest the type i another object.

The "correct" way to do this with respect to all of Scala's features is:

```
class B[T <: ({type LUB[A] = Comparable[_ >: A]})#LUB[T]] extends A[T]
```

Comment: Interesting solution.  You only need to add the type parameter [T] after #LUB in order to let it compile: class B[T <: ({type LUB[A] = Comparable[_ >: A]})#LUB[T]] extends A[T]

Comment: @StefanEndrullis Indeed sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA translates this code to

```
class B[T <: Comparable[(_$1) forSome {type _$1 >: T}]] extends A[T] {
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code produces the same compiler error.